# IoTEdge Module Direct Methods Over Debugging/Simulator - Is it Possible?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I'm developing a multi module scenario using IoTEdge and I need to test Direct Methods Communication using the development environment (Debugging/Simulator).

I've tested the following scenario:

Scenario:

- Device1
- Module1 - Subscribes SetMethodHandlerAsync (Method1)
- Module2 - Calls InvokeMethodAsync (Device1, Module1, Method1)

Results:

- It was impossible to reach the destination module due the missing device registration

  {"message":"Client rramalho-device not found"} not registered

There is any way to debug direct methods communication without pushing modules to Cloud and having the device running directly in the device ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: More specific ... It is possible to debug/execute direct methods without using a real iotedge device ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either simulate a device to debug solutions with multiple modules or simulate a single module application.

A new setting in Azure IoT Tools that enables injection of environment settings into the Visual Studio Code command palette and Azure IoT Edge terminals, you can now build and debug modules on remote devices.

For more information refer this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module?view=iotedge-2020-11#set-up-iot-edge-simulator)

Comment: Thanks for helping. This scenario is an workaround, it forces the image push and having a iotedge module consuming cloud resources isn't it ?. There is no way to debug in Simulator ? Because, sending messages over routes it's possible.